# How to submit the form with a selected value from onchange jquery.timepicker.min.js dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, timepicker

I have created a html form using php. There is a delivery time `<input>` field using class `timepicker`. I'm using `jquery.timepicker.min.js` picker and values can be selected smoothly as desired.

However, if I set `onBlur=this.form.submit` into `<input>`, the default value is submitted instead of the selected value.

If I set into `<input>` `onChange` instead of `onBlur`, the form will not be submitted.

If I add a submit button and don't use any function in `<input>`, the right value is submitted by clicking the submit button.

I'm a real beginner in Javascript and some help would be highly appreciated.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
I have added the code from your answer into the pickers script as follows:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var x = document.getElementById("toimklo").value;
document.getElementById("tklo").innerHTML = x; 
$('input.timepicker').timepicker({ 
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm', 
    interval: 30, 
    minTime: '09:00', 
    maxTime: '18:00', 
    defaultTime: x, 
    startTime: '09:00', 
    dynamic: false, 
    dropdown: true, 
    scrollbar: false }); 
$('tklo').on('selectTime', function() { 
   $('lomake').submit(); });    }); 
</script>
```

toimklo is php `<input>` for delivery time stored in database.
tklo is `<input class="timepicker">` for opening and containing dropdown for selected value.
lomake is name of the form I try to submit.

I guess I have added the code into wrong location?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you if we can have a look on your code.

Answer (score 0):

This JQuery Timepicker has a `selectTime` event here, https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#events

> **selectTime** :  Called after a time value is selected from the timepicker
>   list. Fires before change event

```
$('#myTimePickerField').on('selectTime', function() {
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Submit the form once the time is selected

If your are using a similar package, look for similar events going through the documentation.

Comment: I added the code above into the pickers script as follows: <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var x = document.getElementById("toimklo").value;
  document.getElementById("tklo").innerHTML = x;
  $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
   timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
   interval: 30,
   minTime: '09:00',
   maxTime: '18:00',
   defaultTime: x,
   startTime: '09:00',
   dynamic: false,
   dropdown: true,
   scrollbar: false
  });
  $('tklo').on('selectTime', function() {
      $('lomake').submit();
  });  
 });
</script> but nothing happens. I guess it must be in wrong location?

Comment: <script> above is located on he top of index.php.

Comment: @Hannerz could you update the code into the question you have originally posted, which will help me to read better